# get list of all PHP session_id

Tags: php, list, session, sessionid

Is't possible to get list of all `session_id` in PHP SESSIONS?

Note:
I need maintained some file in the server. One file equal one session. And I need to determine behaviour of old files if SESSION expire.

---

*Thank you all for any advice.*

Comment: I don't think there is - you'd have to keep track of them manually when they are created. What do you need this for?

Comment: I creating mash-up web app and I need to insert one image to session from Flickr in `canvas`. But `canvas` can't use image from remote server. So I save them locally with PHP and then use. But of course I need clean up temporary folder - if session expired file is not necessary. So if new session is created I check if temporary contains only image equal ID active sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd to do this in an old project.

i named the files with the session_id  (something like this: sessionid_some_file.tmp) :

_TMP_PATH_ : path where the files to check are.

```
foreach(new DirectoryIterator(_TMP_PATH_) as $file)
{
    if(preg_match('/(.*)_(.*)_(.*)\.tmp/', $file->getFilename(), $data))
    {
        session_write_close();
        $session_id = $data[1];
        session_id($session_id);
        session_start();
        if(empty($_SESSION))
        {
            unlink(_TMP_PATH_ . $file->getFilename()); 
        }
    }
}
session_write_close();
```

foreach files i get the session_id, open it and test if something inside. (i wrote something after each session opened)

But be carefull, this piece of code has never been in a production environnment.

Answer (score 3):

As others have answered, sessions are stored in the path defined by `session.save_path` in `php.ini` and you can iterate this directory to retrieve a list of every session.

An **alternative approach** would be to change the session storage and move it to a database using [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). You could store all your sessions in a database and do with it whatever you wish.

Comment: That nice idea, but I can't access to change `php.ini` and the `session.save_path` is setup by default to `/dev/shm` non-existing path :(

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do to get a list of all existing session IDs is:

```
preg_grep("/^sess_/", scandir(ini_get("session.save_path")))
```

But that won't tell you which files are still valid. And I don't really get the second part of your question. But it is possible to unserialize them manually to probe for attributes.

Comment: This code doesn't work. Do I echo-it right? `echo $temp = preg_grep("/^sess_/", scandir(ini_get("session.save_path")));
echo $temp[0];`